# Create a left AND right margin not possible

Tags: html, css

thats my pen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/BcjCJ?editors=110

I can not create a left AND a right margin around my whole datagrid. Only the left is possible.

How can I fix that?

I want for example 10px on each side.

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="gridWrapper" class="test">
<div id="gridHeader">     
      <div class="columnHeader">Monday</div>
      <div class="columnHeader">Tuesday</div>        
  </div>

  <div id="gridContent">

    <!-- Monday Column-->
    <div style="background:lightblue;" class="column">
      <!-- ko: foreach-->    
      <div class="custom-row">3333333 111111111111222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222   2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222   2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222   2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222   2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222   2222222222222222222111  1111 111111111111111 111111111111111 1111111111111</div>

      <div class="custom-row">2222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222   22222222222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222 222222222222222222222</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Tuesday Column-->
    <div style="background:green;" class="column">
        <!-- ko: foreach-->
      <div class="custom-row">fsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadffsadffsfsfsd fsd  dffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd  dffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadsad</div>
      <div class="custom-row">fsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadffsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadfffsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadsad</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body,html{
   padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.test {   
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.columnHeader{
  background:yellow;
}
.columnHeader, .column{
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;  /* This causes that all headers have the same width independently from their content */
  width:100%;  
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:1.2em;   
}

#gridHeader{  
  display: flex; /* current version */
 /* This causes that all columns have the same width independently from their content */  
  width:100%; 
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;  
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  height:50px;  
  background:gray;
}

#gridContent{  
  display: -webkit-box;
 /* This causes that all columns have the same width independently from their content */
  width:100%; 
  background:red;
  position:fixed;
  top:50px;
   bottom:0px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

*{ 
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.custom-row{
  height:200px;  /* fix this with flex that the equal height is taken*/

  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  border:1px solid blue;
  background:orange;
}
```

Comment: Your question, as your example, is completely unclear. Please describe in more detail what exactly you need and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @connexo Are you kidding me? What I have tried is setting margins at different positions. And I have a clear question at the end!

Comment: Please remove all unnecessary code from your example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also, which element specificly rejects to accept a margin-right in your code?

Comment: What is your "datagrid"? I can't see an element named like this. If your question is about margins, why did you post an example with CSS of animations, opacity, and so on? I cannot see where is the problem on your code. If you want to set a margin, put the `margin` rule, what's the problem?

Comment: As you asked so patiently, try to remove the `width: 100%;` from the `#gridContent` element.

Comment: In what should that help? When I remove width:100%; I can set margin, left,right whatever. There will be no right margin or lets name it space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to put this css on the `#gridContent`

```
width:calc(100% - 60px); // 2 * 30px ...
margin-left:30px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use fixed positions to position your elements. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpNNzK

```css
#gridWrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.test {
  position: relative;
  animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Firefox */

  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */

  -o-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Opera */
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  /* Firefox */

  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  /* Safari and Chrome */

  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  /* Opera */

  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.columnHeader {
  background: yellow;
}

.columnHeader,
.column {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  /* This causes that all headers have the same width independently from their content */

  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

#gridHeader {
  display: flex;
  /* current version */
  /* This causes that all columns have the same width independently from their content */

  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
}

#gridContent {
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* This causes that all columns have the same width independently from their content */

  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.custom-row {
  height: 200px;
  /* fix this with flex that the equal height is taken*/

  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="gridWrapper" class="test">
  <div id="gridHeader" style="">
    <div class="columnHeader">Monday</div>
    <div class="columnHeader">Tuesday</div>
  </div>

  <div id="gridContent">

    <!-- Monday Column-->
    <div style="background:lightblue;" class="column">
      <!-- ko: foreach-->
      <div class="custom-row">3333333 111111111111222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
        2222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222111 1111 111111111111111 111111111111111 1111111111111</div>

      <div class="custom-row">2222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222 22222222222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222 222222222222222222222</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Tuesday Column-->
    <div style="background:green;" class="column">
      <!-- ko: foreach-->
      <div class="custom-row">fsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadffsadffsfsfsd fsd dffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd dffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadsad</div>
      <div class="custom-row">fsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadffsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadfffsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd
        fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadsad</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You destroyed my sample. A datagrid should have a fixed header and mine has a fixed header. Of course this can be fixed when I removed position fixed, but thats not the point. I presented a sample and asked to add a margin, not remove my feature.